# Find the index of first same group based on value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key

I have a dictionary, which shows one individual's trip, where blank list means walk and list with content means the tube he/she took. I want to find out his/her first tube journey which are indexed as '2,3'.

```
specific_path_legs={0: [],
 1: [],
 2: ['Jubilee'],
 3: ['Jubilee'],
 4: [],
 5: [],
 6: ['Metropolitan'],
 7: ['Metropolitan'],
 8: ['Metropolitan'],
 9: ['Metropolitan'],
 10: [],
 11: [],
 12: [],
 13: [],
 14: ['Northern'],
 15: ['Northern'],
 16: ['Northern'],
 17: ['Northern'],
 18: ['Northern'],
 19: [],
 20: [],
 21: [],
 22: ['Jubilee'],
 23: ['Jubilee'],
 24: ['Jubilee'],
 25: [],
 26: [],
 27: []}
```

I first excluded the walk part and get a legs_nonempty dictionary.

```
legs_nonempty={2: ['Jubilee'],
  3: ['Jubilee'],
 6: ['Metropolitan'],
 7: ['Metropolitan'],
 8: ['Metropolitan'],
 9: ['Metropolitan'],
 14: ['Northern'],
 15: ['Northern'],
 16: ['Northern'],
 17: ['Northern'],
 18: ['Northern'],
 22: ['Jubilee'],
 23: ['Jubilee'],
 24: ['Jubilee']}
```

Then I tried

```
first_leg=[]
for key,value in specific_path_legs.items():
    if value==legs_nonempty.itervalues().next():
        first_leg.append(key)
```

But it returned

```
first_leg=[2,3, 22, 23, 24]
```

I only need [2,3] rather than [2, 3,22, 23, 24]. Any ideas?

Comment: Added an answer. I am assuming you want the smallest value of key for each value present in your dictionary.

Comment: An example of the output you want would really help a lot

Comment: Hope this time, it is easier to be understood.

Comment: I believe this is what my answer is doing. OR, maybe still I am missing something

Comment: Made an edit as your values of dictinary are list. Again I am assuming it is list of single string

Comment: Is this the value which you need? `{'Jubilee': 2, 'Northern': 14, 'Metropolitan': 6}`

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri  Thanks for answering. I don't  want to the first index of different groups. I want to return a the index of first group. If  2, 3 are both  ['Jubilee'], I want to it return [2,3].

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sort dictionary based on keys
import collections
specific_path_legs = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(specific_path_legs.items()))

# Store your info in another dict
path_legs_dict = {}
for key, value in specific_path_legs.items():
    if value and value[0] not in path_legs_dict:
        path_legs_dict[value[0]] = key

print path_legs_dict
# Output: {'Jubilee': 2, 'Northern': 14, 'Metropolitan': 6}
```

I am using `collections.OrderedDict` because the default `dict` object in python is not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Since the keys are incremental starting from 0 just go until you find a non empty value:

```
for i in range(len(specific_path_legs)):
    if specific_path_legs[i]:
        print(i, specific_path_legs[i])
        break
```

Which would give you:

```
(2, ['Jubilee'])
```

if you want to match a specific value also:

```
for i in range(len(specific_path_legs)):
    val = specific_path_legs[i]
    if val and val == "Jubilee":
        print(i ,specific_path_legs[i]
        break
```